# Не везде отображаются русские символы

Tags: python, кодировка, utf-8, python-2.x

С чем может бы связано непринятие русского языка во *Втором питоне* на некоторых машинах?

Например на *Fedora 22*  после добавления в скрипт:

```
# -*- coding: utf -*-
```

проблема решалась, и русские буквы появлялись на экране.

На *CentOS 7*  такой финт не проходит, ругается:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file file.py on line 20, 
>       but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Ругается он на первую попавшуюся функцию:

```
def err():
    print ("Укажите логин, Фамилия, Имя, Отчество")
    sys.exit(0)
```

При этом пробовал строку:

```
# -*- coding: utf -*-
```

менять на:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

не помогло.

А на другой машине с такой же *CentOS7*, русский отображается нормально.

Версия на *CentOS7* - *Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 24 2015, 00:41:19)*

Версия на *fedora 22* - *Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul  5 2015, 14:15:43)*

Обновить  версию на данный момент не представляется возможным, только через месяц, но это не важно.

В чем проблема и как ее можно решить?

Перейти на третью версию можно и, скорее всего, нужно, но сейчас именно по 2 вопрос.

Comment: тестируемые файлы полностью идентичны? проверьте, подсчитав хэш-сумму (например, `md5sum`), или, лучше, скопируйте файл (с помощью `scp`) с «рабочей» *centos7* на «нерабочую».

Comment: тестируемые файлы одинаковые. Сделал их все в три строчки, совственно в функцию ошибки. То есть на всех машинах есть файлик в котором только фунция одна и все. Файлы проверял на хкш-сумму, не все были равны... Сейчас добился что везде один и тот же файл... но радости это не принесло)

Comment: Попровочка, когда файлы создас содержимым. - print ("Укажите логин, Фамилия, Имя, Отчество") -  то  все отобразилось нормально. Иду в свой большой скрипт и снова проблема... менял эту фунцию на латиницу и соответтсвенно  ошибка выпадала в следующем натыкании на  Кирилицу

Comment: *все отобразилось нормально* — значит, проблема внутри файлов. попробуйте скопировать файлы с «рабочей» машины на «нерабочую» (с помощью `scp`). а заодно можете сравнить выводы `hexdump -C файл`.

Comment: Вы правы дело в файле, точней в файлах. которые создал сегодня утром и вчера вечером. не знаю как это все объясняется, но... Вчера и сегодня открым vim  в него скопипастил код и все. он ене сработал, очем был мой пост. затем тоже самое сделал с другими и все работало. данный файл проверил на file -bi utf.py
text/x-python; charset=utf-8
думал. может кодировка самого файла не та. но все впорядке. В общем руками перекопировал и все заработал. И самое странное когда файл рабочий с одного кинул на больного, он так же ругался...Как мне правильней закрыть тему?Ответить на нее и править свой вопрос?

Comment: на ваше усмотрение. если вы найдёте, в чём именно была проблема, переформулируете вопрос (убрав несущественные подробности), и опишете в ответе, как её следует искать, это будет полезным и другим. а в нынешнем же виде вопрос без ответа мало полезен другим, и его стоит закрыть с вердиктом «не по теме → опечатка» или даже вообще удалить (удалить может лишь автор вопроса или модератор).

Comment: и сразу в догонку, решил заменить . пока что  попростому скрипт на баше. на питоновский. Вызывал его из php, заменил на питоновский и получи - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/vpn.py", line 247, in 
    print ("\u041f\u043e\u0435\u0445\u0430\u043b\u0438 )")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)... То есть проблема теперь при передаче) но - файл php  на utf-8,  все на utf-8, а вот как-то сам процесс не сработал... тут куда можно копать? или отдельный вопрос задать. если не разберуь за день?

Comment: *и сразу в догонку* — это уже явно совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, тогда попробую перекроить вопрос и разобраться вчем проблема .. и если нерешу проблему с подобной ситуацией... то удали его...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

гипотезы и общие соображения:

1. согласно [*pep*-у](http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html) (ссылка есть и в самом вопросе) в поисках `coding: кодировка` просматриваются лишь первая и вторая строки файла.
2. возможно, в начале файла есть [*bom*-ы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) или в первые строки «затесались» другие нечитабельные символы, что можно обнаружить, просматривая файл побайтово, например, так:

   ```
   $ hexdump -C файл | less
   ```
3. возможно, в начале файла присутствуют переводы строк «не той системы» (для *unix-like* должны быть `\n`), либо их смесь. как проверить — см. предыдущий пункт.

Comment: Да, как один из вариантов  - самый подходящий. правда сколько не пытался. не получилось ни разу сделать подобное. что и в вопросе. Но попробовав умышленно поставить перенос строки и прочие бомы, ошибку отловить почти смог, но  это не частый случай. но тем не менее. имеет место быть. hexdump -C файл | less - покажет самое начала файла, где лежит шпион. Спасибо.)