# ./filename.py : No such file or directory

Tags: python, bash

Питоновский скрипт находится в некой папке.
В начале файла прописано

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Так же была выполнена команда `chmod u+x ./filename.py` 
при попытке запустить из терминала `./filename.py` отвечает :

> No such file or directory

Вывод `ls -lh`:

```
-rwx--x--x 1 User User 9.8K Sep 27 16:01 filename.py
```

Вывод `which python`:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Были испробованы от безысходности так же

```
#!/usr/bin/python python
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: посмотрите, пожалуйста, на второй и третий пункты из [этого ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453945/178576).

Comment: видимо нет 00000000  23 21 2f 75 73 72 2f 62  69 6e 2f 65 6e 76 20 70  |#!/usr/bin/env p|
00000010  79 74 68 6f 6e 0d 0a 23  2d 2a 2d 20 63 6f 64 69  |ython..#-*- codi|
00000020  6e 67 3a 20 55 54 46 2d  38 20 2d 2a 2d 0d 0a 69  |ng: UTF-8 -*-

Comment: *0d 0a* — это [cr+lf](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) (оно же `\r\n`). может быть, стоит заменить переводы строк на «юниксовые» `\n`? это можно сделать, например, с помощью команды `$ dos2unix файл`.

Comment: спасибо огромное.  помогло.

Comment: оформил в виде развёрнутого ответа. отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr**: см. **Выводы** внизу

---

Чтобы понять откуда берётся пустое имя файла (слева от `:` в сообщении об ошибке):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('./hi.py')
: No such file or directory
32512
```

можно вызвать команду напрямую *без* оболочки (такой как bash):

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> Popen('./hi.py', stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
(b'', b'/usr/bin/env: python\r: No such file or directory\n')
```

результат говорит, что `b'\r'` распознаётся как часть имени команды. На POSIX системах имя файла может быть произвольной последовательностью байтов (кроме нуля `b'\0'` и слэша `b'/'`). Если создать исполняемый файл в PATH, который имеет имя `b'python\r'`:

```
>>> os.symlink('/usr/bin/python', os.path.expanduser('~/bin/python\r'))
```

то ошибка исчезает:

```
>>> os.system('./hi.py')
hi!
0
```

где `hi.py` простой исполняемый скрипт Питона с Виндовыми окончаниями строк:

```
>>> open('hi.py', 'wb').write(b'#!/usr/bin/env python\r\nprint("hi!")')
>>> os.chmod('hi.py', 0b111101101) # rwxr-xr-x
```

Имя команды не видно в первом примере, потому что `b'\r'` в терминале переводит курсор в начало строки:

```
>>> print('abc\r12')
12c
```

то есть буквы `ab` забиваются цифрами `12` в данном примере. Пример демонстрирует традиционное поведение для `CR` (carriage return).

Сам python поддерживает универсальный режим новых строк и поэтому работает с `'\r\n'` и на Unix:

```
>>> os.unlink(os.path.expanduser('~/bin/python\r'))
>>> os.system('python ./hi.py')
hi!
0
```

`#!`-строку (shebang) распознаёт не `python`, и даже не `bash`, а ядро операционной системы (Linux, к примеру). По умолчанию современные версии Unix игнорируют горизонтальный пробел (пробел `b' '` и таб `b'\t'`) в конце `#!`-строки:

```
>>> import string
>>> for ws in string.whitespace:
...   with open('space[%X].py' % ord(ws), 'w') as f:
...     f.write('#!/usr/bin/env python%s\nprint("%X")' % (ws, ord(ws)))
>>> from glob import glob
>>> for cmd in glob('./spac*.py'):
...   os.chmod(cmd, 0b111101101)                                           
...   Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
... 
(b'', b'/usr/bin/env: python\r: No such file or directory\n')
(b'20\n', b'')
(b'A\n', b'')
(b'', b'/usr/bin/env: python\x0b: No such file or directory\n')
(b'9\n', b'')
(b'', b'/usr/bin/env: python\x0c: No such file or directory\n')
```

То есть команда работает для `' \n\t'` и не работает для `'\r\v\f'`.

---

Если хочется запускать скрипт напрямую (не указывая интерпретёр явно), то следует использовать Юниксовые окончания строк, как предложил [@alexander barakin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453928/filename-py-no-such-file-or-directory#comment487886_453928):

```
>>> data = open('./hi.py', 'rb').read()
>>> open('./hi.py', 'wb').write(data.replace(b'\r\n', b'\n'))
34
>>> os.system('./hi.py')
hi!
0
```

Системы контроля версий такие как Mercurial (hg), git наверняка имеют опции, которые помогут заменить новые строки текущей операционной системы на `\n` для `.py` файлов автоматически, если нет возможности **использовать редактор, который подерживает `\n` напрямую**.

Если автор команды, реализованной на Питоне, сам работает только на Винде и не хочет усложнять процесс, то создав [`setup.py`, который определяет setuptools' `entry_points`, можно автоматически поддерживать разные системы (если других несовместимостей нет)](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation):

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='program',
    version='1.2.5',
    description='',
    long_description='',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    url='',
    license='',
    py_modules=['program'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts':
            ['program=program:main']
    }
)
```

где `program.py` файл, для примера, мог быть создан на Винде:

```
>>> open('program.py', 'wb').write(b'#!/usr/bin/env python\r\ndef main():\r\n  print("hi!")\r\n')
52
```

При инсталляции создаются скрипты с правильной `#!`-строкой на Unix системах и соответствующие `.exe` файлы на Windows:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import sys
>>> subprocess.call([sys.executable] + '-m pip install -e .'.split())
Obtaining file:///tmp/prj
Installing collected packages: program
  Running setup.py develop for program
Successfully installed program-1.2.5
0
>>> subprocess.call('program')
hi!
0
```

Прямое чтение машинно-сгенерированного файла подтверждает, что `'\n'` используется на Unix (`docker run -v $PWD:/tmp/prj -it --rm python`) системе:

```
>>> import shutil
>>> open(shutil.which('program'), 'rb').readline()
b'#!/usr/local/bin/python3\n'
```

---

#### Выводы

- `'\r'` в `#!`-строке рассматривается как часть имени команды (`b'python\r'`) на некоторых системах, что вызывает ошибку: *"No such file or directory"* при попытке запуска скрипта
- некоторые терминалы, встречая `'\r'` в выводе программы, переводят курсор в начало строки, поэтому имя файла в сообщении об ошибке  (часть слева от двоеточия) кажется пустым (текст сообщения напечатан поверх него)
- не ясно почему Linux ядро не игнорирует `'\r'` в конце `#!`-строки, как оно это делает для пробелов и табов. Возможно такой выбор сделан, чтобы как раз помочь заметить, что скрипт имеет несовместимые окончания строк (что может указывать на другие проблемы с переносимостью в программе)
- предпочтительный способ обхода этой проблемы—использование редактора, который поддерживает `'\n'` на Windows. Или же, если разработка ведётся исключительно на Винде, то создание `setup.py` с setuptools' `entry_points` как показано выше, чтобы при инсталляции правильные для платформы скрипты-обёртки генерировались бы автоматически.

Answer (score 1):

алгоритм поиска возможных причин подобной ошибки:

1. возможно, в начале файла есть [*bom*-ы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) или в первые строки «затесались» другие нечитабельные символы, что можно обнаружить, просматривая файл побайтово, например, так:

   ```
   $ hexdump -C файл | less
   ```

   про удаление *bom*-ов: [Как убрать BOM из файла?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/433935/178576)
2. возможно, в начале файла присутствуют переводы строк «[не той системы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)» (для unix-like должны быть `\n`, оно же <kbd>lf</kbd>, т.е. *linefeed*, шестнадцатиричный код `0x0a`), либо их смесь.

   - как проверить — см. предыдущий пункт.
   - исправить «досовские» <kbd>cr</kbd>+<kbd>lf</kbd> (`\r\n`, шестнадцатиричной код `0x0d 0x0a`) можно, например, с помощью прогарммы `dos2unix` (из одноимённого пакета):

     ```
     $ dos2unix файл
     ```
   - исправить «маковский» <kbd>cr</kbd> (`\r`, шестнадцатиричной код `0x0d`) можно, например, с помощью прогарммы `mac2unix` (из того же пакета, что и выше):

     ```
     $ mac2unix файл
     ```