# Ошибка при чтении сертификата: PEM_read_bio:no start line

Tags: php, openssl

После чистой переустановки системы (*Debian 7*, *PHP 5.4*, *OpenSSL 1.0.1e*) перестал работать следующий код:

```
$pem = file_get_contents('/path/to/mycert.pem'); 
$res = openssl_pkey_get_public(array($pem, ''));
print_r(openssl_error_string());
```

До переустановки он выдавал сообщение что у сертификата неизвестное шифрование (ГОСТ), теперь же выдает:

> error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

При этом из консоли сертификаты работают нормально:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect domain.ru:443 -CAfile cacert.pem -cert mycert.pem 
(Verify return code: 0 (ok))
```

В переменную `$pem` сертификат загружается нормально, и все данные на месте:

```
$ grep '^-----' mycert.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Пробовал другие команды, например `openssl_get_privatekey()`, но выдают ту же ошибку. Нагуглить решение не получилось.

Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: проверьте переводы строк в файле. посмотреть файл в бинарном виде: `hd /путь/к/файлу | less`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin не совсем понимаю что конкретно надо проверять, не подскажете? В целом по данной команде выдает все что надо..

Comment: [перводы строк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8) в разных системах — разные. `\n` — в *unix-like*, `\r` — в *mac-like*, `\r\n` — в *dos-like*. удостоверьтесь, что присутствуют только *unix-like*. см. дополнительно, например, [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454031/178576).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Данная команда выдает текст такого типа: http://s017.radikal.ru/i413/1510/3d/763eef382d4d.png

Comment: вот и проверьте, что все строки оканчиваются именно символом `\n` (`0x0a`).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Все нормально. Пробовал преобразовывать его заново командой "openssl x509 -inform DER -in mycert.cer -outform PEM -out mycert.pem". Ошибка все равно на месте.